# What can replace milk, for vegan pancakes without eggs?

Tags: vegan, pancakes

Please see the question in the title. My goal is to make vegan pancakes without:

1. eggs,
2. milk,
3. any milk alternative that uses [Natural Flavours](https://empoweredsustenance.com/non-dairy-milks/), like soy or coconut milk.

I live in Ontario, Canada and visited these 6 stores, yet all their soy and coconut milks contain Natural Flavours: Loblaws, Longo's,  Metro,  [Noah's Natural Foods](https://www.blogto.com/grocery/noahs/), Whole Foods Market, [Your Good Health](https://www.yourgoodhealth.com/#locations).

Comment: Purchase dried soybeans.  Make your own soy milk.  It is not a difficult process.

Comment: I have never seen soy or coconut milk with vegetable oil added. Do you mean that they contain fat? That's what they are, a suspension of the fat of the coconut (or the soy) in water. So maybe you should clarify what your question is. Is it about finding a liquid to use in the pancakes (which can be anything)? Or have you decided to use a nut milk and are asking why the ones you have found contain oil, in which case you should explain why you think they contain it? Or something else?

Comment: @rumtscho You're correct. I've removed 'vegetable oils'.

Answer (score 2):

I would also add Rice Milk is a good alternative also and can be home made.

Comment: Hi, and welcome! I must say that we don't allow any discussion on potential health effects of food, so I had to remove that part. But thank you for giving this suggestion, it is an interesting one.

Answer (score 2):

Coconut, almond and soy milk can be made from scratch (with scratch being either coconut or dried soybeans) with home-grade equipment. Methods and equipment needed are well documented and out of scope here.

Alternatively, cashew-based cream substitute can be easily made (just blend boiled cashews thoroughly, adding only as much water as needed to keep the blender happy) - this is close enough to cream that it can be churned into ice cream, and a traditional indian ingredient too (eg as a thickener in kormas and "shahi" style dishes) - although this might end up just too rich and stodgy in a pancake.

Mind that while some "natural flavours" containing products are not vegan, some are - best check the brands offered closely, they might have statements available on their website or be able to tell you upon a phone call or email.

In the unlikely case there is no trustworthy (by your standards) soy milk but soy yoghurt available, diluting such should give a viable milk substitute for that purpose (diluted yoghurts are not uncommon as a buttermilk substitute, and buttermilk is a well established pancake ingredient).

Also, be aware that asian grocers will usually carry unadulterated (by label) coconut milk, and often also soymilk and/or soymilk powder.

Also, mind that legume flour based pancakes are part of some culinary traditions, and usually these recipes do not contain milk or milk substitutes. North Indian Besan Ka Cheela is a tasty example for a savory pancake of that style, the recipe can be adapted to a sweet pancake readily.

Answer (score 0):

I make pancakes using:

- Oat Flour,
- Banana,
- Water,
- little bit of oil,
- pinch of salt

In my opinion it is the best option.

Other one which is better for no sweet option:

- wheat flour,
- Linseed (blended if can - soaked in a boil water)
- little bit of oil,
- pinch of salt

For milk i suggest you to try this:

- blend blended coconut shrims with boil water, then filter the water and use    coconut shrims again with new water . I make 1.2l of milk this way

  You can add this milk to the first recipe by replacing water.

Answer (score 0):

You can use carbonated mineral water as milk substitute .You can find in every polish or eastern Europiien store.